# Conditional statements and boolean values

Tags: java

When I click on a PaintSwatch, I want them to highlight themselves (setFrameThickness and setFrameColor). However, I want to make it so only one can be highlighted at a time. I included 2 conditions that it must satisfy and the boolean part isnt working how I thought it would because I am still able to highlight multiple PaintSwatches.

```
import wheels.users.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class PaintSwatch extends Ellipse
{
private ColorHolder _holder; //Swatches setColor of this peer object
private boolean _clicked;

public PaintSwatch(Color c,ColorHolder holder){
    super(c);

    _holder = holder;

    _clicked = false;

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if (!_holder.getColor().equals(super.getColor()) && _clicked == false)
        {
         super.setFrameColor(Color.BLACK);
         super.setFrameThickness(3);
         _holder.setColor(super.getColor());
         _clicked=true;

        }

        else if(_holder.getColor().equals(super.getColor()) && _clicked == true)
        {
         super.setFrameThickness(0);
         super.setFrameColor(Color.WHITE);
         _holder.setColor(Color.RED);
         _clicked=false;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the interaction between both PaintSwatches. Your mouse event does only change the status of the PaintSwatch clicked on.

However, you need to call the other PaintSwatches to change accordingly. You could do that via a function in the parent object of all PaintSwatches, directly (then all PaintSwatches need to be registered with each other) or using Observers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When a mouse click occurs, only the object being clicked receives the `mouseClicked()` call.  You need to somehow track the currently-selected `PaintSwatch` and deselect it when a new `PaintSwatch` is selected.